# send data from processing to arduino

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing, serial-communication

I am trying to send 70 values from Processing to Arduino (as fast as possible), in order for Arduino to feed with these values a servo driver shield. What I tried to do in my code is to send the data one by one and each time a value is received Arduino confirms that to Processing in order to move to the next one. However my code doesn't works properly. Please have a look below to see what mistakes do I have, or if you have a better solution for the procedure please share it! Thank you for you time!

### Arduino Code

```
int val[70];
void setup()   {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
 Serial.write(0);
   for (int i=0;i<70;i++){       
     if(Serial.available()>0)
{ 
     val[i]=Serial.read();
     Serial.write(i);     
     Serial.flush();        
   }
    }
if (val[0]==1 & val[1]==2)
{
    Serial.println("done");
} else {
    Serial.println("error");
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

### Processing Code

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
int last;
byte a[] = { 111, 112, 113, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
             99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
             99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
             99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
             99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
             99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
             99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 114, 115, 116 };
void setup()
{
  size (200, 200);
  String portName = Serial.list()[6];
  myPort = new Serial (this, portName, 9600);
   delay(2000);
}
void draw()
{
  while (myPort.available()>0)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<70; i++)
    {
      last = myPort.read();
      if (int(last) == i-1)
      { 
        myPort.clear();
        myPort.write(a[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you be more specific about the problem that you're having, beyond "it doesn't work properly"?  Also, removing the extra empty lines between lines of code will make it easier to read your post.

Comment: To send as fast as possible is counter-intuitive to confirm every byte of data with the sender :) Just have the arduino read the bytes as fast as they come and do with them in accordance with whatever logic you have defined. in addition, while (myPort.available()>=0) does not make sense. If there is nothing available, while read the port buffer? Change to: while (myPort.available() > 0)

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I understood my mistake with (myPort.available() > 0). Even if I don't confirm each value, I have somehow to confirm that the String of data has been loaded correctly before a new one is sent. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you know the size of the array with data. As the data arrive to the Arduino save the bytes to a similar array. Then when all the data has arrived, use the data to do whatever they are meant to do. As to confirm the validity of the data, one way is to use CRC to generate a checksum on the data. So before the sender sends the data, generate the checksum, send the data, send the checksum. On the receiver end, save the data in an array, save the checksum in a variable. Then generate a checksum on the received data. If the generated result matches the received checksum the data is good.